# $_SESSION end while redirect to another page

Tags: php, session

I have a script that use a $_SESSION to login and register.

```
$_SESSION['loggedin']
```

Somehow when I try to submit a form and the form give me a redirect to another web such as Perfect Money API. When I finish the payment it will redirect back to my site but all the $_SESSION is gone and my login session is end.

I have to login again to be able to access the site.

Which string to save the $_SESSION while i'm in another page API and back with the request?

Comment: If after redirection, the Url opens in the same browser instance, then this shouldn't happen.

Comment: Cookie of `PHPSESSID` should be sent to the server. Can you do a `print_r($_COOKIE);` to check what all cookies you receive.

Comment: @nice_dev "When I finish the payment it will redirect back to my site" it means in the same browser
Array ( [PHPSESSID] => n3u5qi3uasl5b1nfk3van5b809 )

Comment: This is unlikely that chrome destroys your session.

Comment: Take a look at here. https://support.google.com/mail/thread/37410180?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution.
It was google chrome problem. I try microsoft edge browser and it work fine.

Don't know what happen with google chrome.

This also happen on other users Take a look at here. https://support.google.com/mail/thread/37410180?hl=en

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/62111771?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

From the way you explained it I think you are redirecting the `form` page to Perfect Money API using the same browser tab.
Maybe you can try to use an `action` with `target="_blank"` in order to don't lose the `$_SESSION['loggedin']` value. Like this:

```
<form action="/your_action_page.php" method="..." target="_blank">
```

Other approach might be to send and receive the `$_SESSION['loggedin']` to the action page. Then use it to create and assign a new `$_SESSION` so that it doesn't lose the value you want.

For last, make sure you have `session_start()` before all your PHP code. And other thing, try to play with the different settings of your `$_SESSION`. Like this:

```
// SESSION CACHE LIMITER
session_cache_limiter('private');       // THERE ARE 4 TYPES OF CACHE LIMITER

// SESSION CACHE EXPIRATION 
session_cache_expire(30);               // TIME IN SECONDS

// SESSION START
session_start();                        // MUST BE BEFORE ALL PHP CODE
```

I know these suggestions could be helpless, but it's just a point of view of what I would try to do.

Comment: It's a form with submit data actually. After finish the payment, the perfect money button will show and when we click on "go back" it will redirect me to another page in my site

Comment: Since you are opening and redirecting web pages from different apps maybe that is the problem. You need to find a way to preserve the $_SESSION value. At this point I would start debugging and printing the $_SESSION value in the diferent stages of your project. Try to find and understand what it's happening to the value. Good luck!

Comment: Already did this, $_SESSION value is exist before page submit, but after redirecting from perfect money the $_SESSION value is missing

Comment: Have you tried to open the action page (Perfect Money API) in a new tab (target:"_blank") without closing your current web page application? Does it have the same result?

Comment: <form id="pmyes" action="https://perfectmoney.is/api/step1.asp" method="POST" target="_blank">
The result is same, after finish payment, and click on confirm. It will redirect me to my web and destroy all $_SESSION

Comment: Damn... So aparently the redirect is creating a new instance of your application/page/login. Causing the destruction of the $_SESSION. Is there a way for you to embed the API inside your project? I mean, with no redirect or new pages?

Comment: After click it will redirect to perfect money page and finish the payment. I'm using php 7.4 and this is so confusing me

Comment: That struggle your are facing is called programming. Don't give up! Everyone that programs faced a million times the same struggle your are facing with! Think! Research! Be creative! But above all, just Have Fun! Good luck! I really mean it!

Comment: One last thing, I know that I wasn't able to really help you. However I gave time and effort for that to happen. If you have the same opinion has I, please upvote my answer. I will appreciate it very much. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your upvote! I really mean it! It's awesome that you find an answer to the problem. Congratulations! Keep up the good work. And never forget to Have Fun!